# ¿Cómo actualizar otra Base de Datos (diferente a la principal) por cada registro?

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine, symfony5

Estoy intentanto que por cada operación (***Crud***) en mi aplicación de Symfony, se actualice además de mi Base de Datos principal de la aplicación, otra Base de Datos que está en otro servidor.. Algo así como un *trigger* por cada operación realizada en la aplicación hacia la segunda BBDD también.

Consideré la idea de emplear un ***Subscriber*** o ***Evento*** desde el mismo Framework, entrar a los Repositorios (`Repository`) que Doctrine (el ORM) me da, y correr los `Queries` que necesite...
Pero no tengo idea de cómo desarrollar ese flujo, y especificar la otra Base de Datos en los Repositories..

En principio, necesito que al ocurrir un registro, se ejecute inmediatamente una consulta y eventualmente el registro en la otra BBDD... ¿Cómo lo puedo lograr?

(El driver de ambas Bases de Datos es PostgreSQL)

Comment: Te recomiendo que te documentes del lado del motor de Base de Datos y que hagas en PostgreSQL la llamada REPLICACIONES SINCRÓNICAS entre base de datos, así estén en el mismo servidor o fuera (interno o externo), de esta manera garantizas de forma más segura la integridad de los datos así tengas una falla de conexión, si lo hace por código deberás contemplar un sin fin de fallas para garantizar dicha integridad.

Comment: Gracias @AlbertoMarun por tu colaboración!. En base a tu respuesta, no se trata tanto de replicar la misma Base de Datos, ya que la otra es diferente, pero comparte ciertos datos con la BBDD principal, y son esos los datos que se requieren actualizar solamente

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada, debes de declarar los distintos tipos de conexiones en este caso te recomiendo este link https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html. Ahora para el tema de usar dicha conexion seria:

```php
class UserController extends AbstractController
{
    public function index(ManagerRegistry $doctrine): Response
    {
        // Both methods return the default entity manager
        $entityManager = $doctrine->getManager();
        $entityManager = $doctrine->getManager('default');

        // This method returns instead the "customer" entity manager
        $customerEntityManager = $doctrine->getManager('customer');

        // ...
    }
}
```

Ahora, bien, creo que a nivel de código estás intentando solucionar un problema que en infraestructura pudiera ser mas sencillo. La primera pregunta que uno debe de hacerse es para que se necesita esta inserción en esta segunda base de datos? o que motivo se tiene? ahora bien dado que estas usando una segunda conexión los ids de las transacciones puideran no ser las mismas por lo que no seria una replica de la primera base, otra solución posible es el uso de una configuracion de esclavo-maestro, esto que es? significa que cuando se escriba en el maestro, la misma información es insertada en el esclavo con el mismo ID, esto presenta 2 ventajas, te olvidas de hacer esta inserción y segunda, la base de datos esclava puede fungir como entidad para sacar reportes y/o otras operaciones mas pesadas sin influenciar al nodo maestro.